# Run Airflow Webserver and Scheduler on different servers

Tags: airflow

I was wondering if the Airflow's scheduler and webserver Daemons could be launched on different server instances ?

And if it's possible, why not use serverless architecture for the flask web server ?

There is a lot of resources about multi nodes cluster for workers but I found nothing about splitting scheduler and webserver.

Has anyone already done this ? And what may be the difficulties I will be facing ?

Answer (score 1):

I would say the minimum requirement would be that both instance should have

- Read(-write) access to the same AIRFLOW_HOME directory (for accessing DAG scripts and the shared config file)
- Access to the same database backend (for accessing shared metadata)
- Exactly the same Airflow version (to prevent any potential incompatibilities)

Then just try it out and report back (I am really curious ;) ).

Comment: Yes I will ! :) 
Also, does Airflow's webserver really need to access the dag directory ? I though only the metadatas where enough

Comment: @RonanT The webserver actually hast to access the dag directory to parse the DAG files. Since 1.10.7, there is a ["DAG Serialization" feature](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/dag-serialization.html) that aims at decoupling the webserver from DAG parsing. Although, it is disabled by default and I do not know how mature it is.

Comment: thank you for this link, I missed it in the documentation. I think I will wait for a complete stateless airflow webserver, it will be easier to setup. But if I manage to have time to do it I will report back !